# What are the conditions for the string of a pendulum to become slack?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, centripetal-force

Suppose the bob of a stationary pendulum is given a sharp hit to impart it some horizontal speed. Now what are the conditions for the string to become slack after rotating a particular angle?

- resultant centripetal force should be zero.

  -tension in the string should be zero

  Or what?

  And when the string becomes slack, does it have GPE only or GPE and KE both?

Comment: I don't think that you can properly analyze this problem without taking tensile strain into account which means the possible presence of elastic potential energy in the system as well.

Comment: The instant it becomes slack, the tension in the string will equal zero.

Comment: Suppose the string is inextensible. When it becomes slack,i.e, when the tension equals zero, should the centripetal force also equals zero?